# Jupyter notebook stuck at plotting a tensor (Tensorflow 2) using matplotlib (CPU going 100%)

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, tensor

I'm following a video tutorial and using matplotlib to plot a tensorflow tensor in a Jupyter Notebook.
The cell just stuck and one CPU went 100%.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
tfd = tfp.distributions
tfb = tfp.bijectors

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# %matplotlib inline

normal = tfd.Normal(loc=0, scale=1)
n = 10000
z = normal.sample(n)

scale = 4.5
shift = 7
scale_and_shift = tfb.Chain([tfb.Shift(shift), tfb.Scale(scale)])
x = scale_and_shift.forward(z)
plt.hist(z, bins=60, density=True)
plt.show()
```

In the tutorial I'm following, it runs smoothly. But in my attempt it got stuck. **Why it doesn't work in my case? Is there any package I should install?** `z` is a tensor, is it OK to plot it directly?

I noticed if I use `plt.hist(z.numpy(), bins=60, density=True)` it works. But still wondering why plotting `z` directly does not work in my environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, that's not a missing package problem and generally there's no problem in plotting tensors directly. For example you could have done `plt.plot(z)` without as issue. If you check `plt.hist` [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) you can see this:

> The return value is a tuple (n, bins, patches) or ([n0, n1, ...], bins, [patches0, patches1, ...]) if the input contains multiple data.

In your case, since you're plotting sample values from the distribution (with `z` being a [10000] shaped tensor), you are on the second category ([n0, n1, ...]) and you're actually creating 10000 overlapping histograms. To make it clear, see this for `s=4`:
[image]

That's why your CPU is overloaded - trying to create 10000 histograms at once (also thats why each line is a different color --> different histograms).

When you use `tensor.numpy()` it converts the Tensor to a NumPy array using and is able to create the histogram correctly.

PS not sure why it's working in the tutorial. Maybe trey're using different packages' version - but `z.numpy()` should give you the same results